# Asp Net Core Multiple Connection Strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'll try to add more information as requested:

**appsettings.json**

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Debug": "server=Server;user id=myuser;password=password;port=3306;database=database1;",
    "Demo": "server=Server;user id=myuser;password=password;port=3306;database=database2;"
  }
```

Both servers are the same, but two different databases (1 and 2 for example).

**Startup.cs**:

```
services.AddTransient<AppDb>(_ => new Controllers.AppDb(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Database1"]));
            services.AddTransient<AppDb>(_ => new Controllers.AppDb(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Database2"]));
```

I have both this services for the ConnectionStrings, currently the Database isn't working.

**AppDb.cs**

```
namespace ProjectDatabase.Controllers
{
    public class AppDb
    {
        public MySqlConnection Connection { get; }

                   

        public AppDb(string connectionString)
        {
            Connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);    
       
        }

        public void Dispose() => Connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I have this that calls and connects to the database, but it's only connecting to Database1.

**ClientsController**

```
namespace ProjectDatabase.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ClientsController : ControllerBase
    {
        public ClientsController(AppDb db)
        {
            Db = db;
        }

        // GET api/clients
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetLatest()
        {
            await Db.Connection.OpenAsync();
            var query = new clientsQuery(Db);
            var result = await query.LatestClientsAsync();
            return new OkObjectResult(result);
        }

       
        public AppDb Db { get; }
    }
}
```

I place the Get Request for the Database1.

Question: I already have connected to Database1 and would like to connect to Database2 one at a time, how can achieve this ? How can I tell the app to Get the data from Database2 ? I already have the 2nd Connection String how can i access both of them ?

Edited for more clarity.

Comment: Why arent you using Entity framework or dapper, or any ORM?

Comment: Also, what error do you get?

Comment: If I take the comment out of that line I'll get this error: InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: How the application knows what connection do you want? How would you like to change connections?

Comment: That's what Im trying to figure out, I would want to get the data from both Databases on user command, for example, User wants to get all clients from Debug, gets it. User now wants to change the database to the second one called Demo and get the list of all clients from that database. I essentially want to connect to both Databases, have the requests done and ready to go so that in Angular, the user selects Database1 or Database2 and gets the list of clients.

Comment: it is a web application. You have to keep somewhere user choice or user will select each time? You will have to create the dbcontext manulally inside of the base controller using some kind of route value then. Are you ready to use it instead of dependancy injection? Or you will have to create 2 dbcontext using DI and  select one of them each time.

Comment: When and how do you know which connection should be used? Have you got any paremeter in the Controller selected from user client? It's an user configuration? It's a global setting?

Comment: In my AppDb.cs file ? Can I just create another MySqlConnection ? called Con for example, the only thing is I don't know how i'm going to say that Connection is the Debug database and the Con MySqlConnection is the Demo database, can you do that ?

Comment: This post needs  more details and clarity

Comment: Edited to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Startup.cs:**

```
 services.AddTransient<AppDb>(_ => new Controllers.AppDb(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Debug"], Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Demo"]));
```

**AppDb.cs**

```
 public class AppDb
    {

       
        public MySqlConnection conDebug { get; }

        public MySqlConnection conDemo { get; }


        

        public AppDb(string connectionStringDebug, string connectionStringDemo)
        {

            conDebug = new MySqlConnection(connectionStringDebug);

            Hashtable hasDB = new Hashtable();
            hasDB["debug"] = conDebug;

                      
        }

        public void Dispose() => conDebug.Dispose();
    }  
    
}
```

Solved.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want to switch between connection that depends on environment.

So you can look into asp.net configuration.

Create 2 env files and then put your connection strings into them.

For example:

*appsettings.Development.json*

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "MySql": "Dev DB connection string"
  },
```

*appsettings.Demo.json*

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "MySql": "Demo DB connection string"
  },
```

and your setup code will looks like this

```
services.AddTransient(_ => new 
Controllers.AppDb(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:MySql"]));
```

So after that manipulations you just need to switch environment and you will get right connection string.

Read about how to setup multi environment configuration you can here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments

Comment: Is it not possible to do that on the appsettings.json file ? How would I switch between connections ? The idea is to have, for example, both connections to the 2 Databases ready to go, GET the data from one database, and then select the second database to get the data from that database. Essentially I would have both connections ready to use and later in Angular I would ask the User which Database does he want to connect to.

Answer (score -1):

```
namespace ProjectDatabase.Controllers
{
    public class AppDb
    {
        public MySqlConnection Connection { get; }

        public MySqlConnection Con { get; }
        

        public AppDb(string connectionString)
        {
            Connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

            Con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        }

        public void Dispose() => Connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This is my AppDb.cs, my `controller` for the connection, what if I add a second MySqlConnection and then in my ClientsController I specify the connection to be open:

```
namespace ProjectDatabase.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ClientsController : ControllerBase
    {
        public ClientsController(AppDb db)
        {
            Db = db;
        }

        // GET api/clients
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetLatest()
        {
            await Db.Connection.OpenAsync();
            var query = new clientsQuery(Db);
            var result = await query.LatestClientsAsync();
            return new OkObjectResult(result);
        }

       
        public AppDb Db { get; }
    }
}
```

Instead of having await `Db.Connection.OpenAsync()` I could create another `Controller` and do await `Db.Con.OpenAsync()` which will be my 2nd Connection to the my 2nd database.

Is this something that will not cause me any problems or has any cons to it ?